# Using SQL Loader with condition

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I need to load a CSV file into Oracle everytime this CSV is updated and thought about using `SQL LOADER`. The point is that I need to perform some verifications such as:

- If the record `Key` is already in the database but the `name` column is different, `UPDATE` the name;
- If the record `Key` desn't exist in the database, `INSERT` the record;

How I can do it with SQL LOADER?

Comment: `SQL*Loader`, doesn't support an `UPDATE` operation. Since you have it as CSV file, you can consider storing it as external table.

Comment: Load your data into temporary table (not GTT) using sqlldr and then merge.

Comment: @OracleUser, thanks for your reply. Can you tell me more about it? I never did anything like this.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, thanks for your reply I will strongly consider this solution. Maybe this can be the easier way by now. Thanks!